# Do I need to explicitly close connection?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm holding one instance of `MongoClient` and `DB` in my application, and every time that I want to execute some operation I call `getCollection()`.
I'm wondering if I need to explicitly close the connection, just like `connection.close()` in JDBC.

To emphasize, I have only one `MongoClient` instance. My question is not about closing `MongoClient` but closing the connections I believe it opens when I'm calling `getCollection()`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, you do not need to close connections to DB - your only connection is via MongoClient and as the documentation states - it handles connection pooling for you.

The only resource that you would want to clean up would be a [cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html) which you should [close()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#close%28%29) when you're done with it.

Comment: the links are broken

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.close/

Answer (score 9):

You should close if you have many MongoClient.

> The MongoClient instance actually represents a pool of connections to
>   the database; you will only need one instance of class MongoClient
>   even with multiple threads.
>
> MongoClient.close() to clean up resources
>
> MongoClient.close() - closes the underlying connector, which in turn
>   closes all open connections. Once called, this Mongo instance can no
>   longer be used.

More: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/

Comment: Of course if you have many instances without having many MongoDB instances in your app then that is bad programming

Comment: I have only one MongoClient instance. My question is not about closing MongoClient but closing the connections I believe it opens when I'm calling getCollection.