# How to @SuppressWarnings: "Resource leak: 'client' is never closed"

Tags: java

I have statement:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
```

and there si warning:

```
[Java] Resource leak: 'client' is never closed
```

According to [Do I need to explicitly close connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938153/do-i-need-to-explicitly-close-connection), I don't need to close connection.

How can I suppress this warning? @SuppressWarnings("???")

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the @SuppressWarnings({ "resource" }) should remove the warning for a potential resource leak. Adding a list for other ones, it's for Eclipse but they should be fairly similar for reference.

[What is the list of valid @SuppressWarnings warning names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205995/what-is-the-list-of-valid-suppresswarnings-warning-names-in-java)

Comment: @SuppressWarnings is misspelled, but the wonderful nazi rules of stackoverflow don't allow me to edit it, because an edit needs to be at least 6 characters. Also, note that the braces are optional.