# MongoClient close method is deprecated. How can I replace it to avoid the deprecated method?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using mongo java driver 3.9.0 and the close() method from MongoClient is deprecated.
The problem I see is that MongoClient implements Closebale, and that's why there is this close() method in there.
I couldn't find any replace to it yet and I was looking here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#close--

How can I replace it so I don't have to use the deprecated method?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to explicitly close connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938153/do-i-need-to-explicitly-close-connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you are referring is for old api. Starting from 3.7 you should use [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoClient.html) and it [close()](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoClient.html#close--) method. New API came with a lot of changes, [more details.](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/driver/getting-started/quick-start/)

Comment: It puts me one step close, but I'm now having problems to use the com.mongodb.client.MongoClient. I'll update the question

Comment: Actually, I'll just write here in the comment. I need to parse the com.mongodb.MongoClient to the new com.mongodb.client.MongoClient. That's what I had before: MongoCredential credential = createCredentials(repository);
  ServerAddress serverAdress = new ServerAddress(repository.getLocation().getHost(),
    repository.getLocation().getPort());
  MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().serverSelectionTimeout(10000).build();
  return new MongoClient(serverAdress, credential, options);

Comment: How do I properly parse that to the new way? Not being able to figure this out

Comment: And the link from the answer will help you [more details](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/driver/getting-started/quick-start/) One of the way `MongoClients.create("mongodb://hostOne:27017,hostTwo:27018")`