# I am using PyMongo. Do I have to close a MongoClient after use?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I am using PyMongo, and I have some questions about connection and cursor.

A. Do I have to close a cursor? I want to know because I really want to do something like this.

```
for s in collection.find():
   print(s)
```

B. Do I have to close a MongoClient manually? Will it affect the connection polling feature of PyMongo?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
client = MongoClient(url)               

db = client['test']                    
collection = db['students']             

# QUERY
cursor = collection.find()
for s in cursor:
    print(s)

cursor.close()         # Is this required?
client.close()         # Is this required?
```

I am not sure if there are any differences.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python MySQLdb: connection.close() VS. cursor.close()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504340/python-mysqldb-connection-close-vs-cursor-close)

Comment: @BlueRobin No, it is for another database and package. What I really want to know is if client.close() affect PyMongo's connection polling features.

Comment: I don't believe it would affect the pooling features as you are freeing up allocated resources and not the connection entirely. I may be wrong, however.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.close/)
`cursor.close()` frees allocated resources to that cursor. However, the server will automatically do this after a time period, and it is not (entirely) needed.

As shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938153/do-i-need-to-explicitly-close-connection) it is probably good practice to close cursors.

As shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495975/why-is-it-recommended-not-to-close-a-mongodb-connection-anywhere-in-node-js-code) it would be best to reuse connections and to not close the client.